# Android Google Maps v2 testing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an activity that displays a list on markers based on the state of a model.
Whenever the model's state is changed, the markers are refreshed to display the new location or display any new markers.

I want to test this behavior but `GoogleMap` does not provide a `.getMarkers()` method or similar to know which markers are shown on the map.

The question is, how can I test both the number of `Marker`s and the `LatLng` or each marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep an `ArrayList` of all plotted markers and iterate through to find the one you want?

or there is a [3rd party mapping library](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) that you can call `getMarkers`, getPolygons etc..

Answer (score 0):

Thats just an idea but you can store you marker (latlng, id, image, etc) on an `ArrayList`. Then when you create your marker, assign `foreach` the **id** and on click retrieve the **id** to get all information's from your `Array`.